# Too many events from threads blocking UI

Tags: .net, multithreading, events

My software analyses files with data in them. In order to have an accurate idea of the analysis progress, it **raises an event each time a file line is analysed**. The analysis process is executed **in different threads** than the UI thread. The UI thread then handles the events and updates progress bars.

When only one file is analysed at a time, the software works wonderfully, but if multiple files are being analysed at the same time (up to 4 files in 4 different threads), it looks like there are so many "file read events" being handled that the UI events like mouse clicks on buttons, window resize events and window moved events are put at the end of the event queue. The result being that these UI events are only handled much later than when they were raised.

For example : When I press the cancel button at the bottom (picture below). The button.click event is only handled when the progress bars are all the way filled. The buttons don't highlight when I hover above them, I can't resize the window, etc.

[image]

My question is : Is there a way I can prioritize events from the UI? Or can I handle the analysis events and update the progress bars in a different thread? How do I keep these buttons responsive in real time?

I know that if I reduce the amount of events being raised I'll achieve what I want, but I want to know if there is another solution.

Comment: Only the UI thread can update the UI.  Do you really need a line by line status?

Comment: Calling BeginInvoke or ReportProgress (don't make us guess, the screenshot is useless) a *lot* less frequently is the solution.  You only have to keep human eyes entertained.  And only have to call it 100 times to fill a default progress bar, right now you are calling it *thousands* of times.  So a very simple quick fix is to only call it if the percentage of progress is actually different.

Comment: True... Didn't think of that. Thanks. Calling Invoke btw.

Comment: Just update the bars with a form timer.  Every half-second is usually enough for user feedback.  Avoiding the stuffing up the GUI input queue with redundant messages is one of the few times I recommend polling with a timer instead of posting messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this I'd use a different approach: make all your threads update simple counters (internal data, as in Dim Progress1 As Integer) and make the main (UI) thread read the counters on a Timer event (e.g. every 100 ms). That is fast enough for the user and would not "clog" your UI thread. You could use SyncLock when reading/writing those counters to make sure you get consisting data.

Notice that too many UI updates would waste CPU cycles that you could use doing real work!

Comment: I've just noticed user Martin James said the same thing yesterday in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SemaphoreSlim`class to throttle the amount of concurrent threads that can do an analysis at the same time.

Maybe, even two concurrent analysis are too much if your hard disk is not fast enough and/or you have a single processor.

If the files are sort and you can load the whole thing in memory, allow the same concurrent analysis than the number of available processors. If the files are large try to process large chunks of information each time.

You may have multiple cores, but if your hard disk is not fast and/or you force it to jump from place to place reading chunks... the hard disk will become the bottleneck.

Is important that you do some tuning to find which is the right balance.